# How to get subscriptions working with Apollo GraphQL?

Tags: websocket, publish-subscribe, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I'm going to post a lot of code for context. I haven't seen a tutorial that shows both the client and server yet, so I'm trying to piece this all together.

## Code

### Client

#### Network interface

```
const subscriptionClient = new SubscriptionClient(`ws://localhost:8031/`, {
    reconnect: true
});

const networkInterface = createNetworkInterface({
    uri: 'http://localhost:8030/graphql'
});

const subscriptionInterface = addGraphQLSubscriptions(networkInterface, subscriptionClient);

const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
    networkInterface: subscriptionInterface
});
```

#### Component

```
const SUBSCRIPTION_QUERY = gql`
    subscription onBranchUpdated($id: UUID!) {
        branchUpdated(id: $id) {
            browser
            crawlId
            startDate
            endDate
            baseUrl
            totalPages
            currentPage
        }
    }
`;


class BranchPage extends React.PureComponent {

    render() {
        *snip*
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.data.subscribeToMore({
            document: SUBSCRIPTION_QUERY,
            variables: {
                id: this.props.match.params.id,
            },
            updateQuery: (prevResult, {subscriptionData}) => {
                log('updateQuery',prevResult,subscriptionData);
            }
        });
    }
}

export default graphql(gql`
    query getBranch($id: UUID!) {
        branch(id: $id) {
            id
            browser
            crawlId
            startDate
            endDate
            baseUrl
            totalPages
            currentPage
        }
    }
`, {
    options: ({match: {params}}) => ({
        variables: {
            id: params.id,
        }
    })
})(BranchPage);
```

### Server

#### graphql.schema.graphqls

```
schema {
    query: Query
    mutation: Mutation
    subscription: Subscription
}

type Branch {
    id: UUID!
    *snip*
}

type Subscription {
    branchUpdated(id: UUID!): Branch
}
```

#### resolvers

```
const resolverMap = {
    Query: {
        async branch(obj, {id}, context, info) {
            *snip*
            return branch;
        },
    },
    Mutation: {
        async updateBranch(_, req) {
            let {id, ...updates} = req;
            let branch = await db::queryOne("select * from Branches where id=?", [id]);
            updates = getUpdates(req);
            Object.assign(branch, updates);
            await db::mutate("update Branches set ? where id=?", [updates, id]);
            pubSub.publish(topics.BRANCH_UPDATED, {branchUpdated: branch});
            return branch;
        },
    },
    Subscription: {
        branchUpdated: {
            resolve: (payload, args, context, info) => {
                log('RESSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSoLVE',payload,args);
                return payload;
            },
            subscribe: withFilter(() => pubSub.asyncIterator(topics.BRANCH_UPDATED), (payload, variables) => {
                log('FILTERRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR');
                return payload.branchUpdated.id === variables.id;
            }),
        },
    },
};
```

#### pubSub

```
import { PubSub } from 'graphql-subscriptions';

const pubSub = new PubSub();
export default pubSub;
```

#### WebSocket server

```
const wsServer = createServer((request, response) => {
    response.writeHead(404);
    response.end();
});

wsServer.listen(WS_PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Websocket server: http://localhost:${WS_PORT}`)
});

const subscriptionServer = SubscriptionServer.create(
    { 
        schema,
        execute,
        subscribe,
    },
    {
        server: wsServer,
        path: '/',
    }
);
```

## Problem

When I load the page with this component, it uses the network interface to load the data and it renders correctly. After that, I want to component to subscribe to updates over a websocket to keep it up to date. That's the part I'm having trouble with.

In Chrome dev tools, I can see "updateQuery" gets hit immediately, although I'm not sure why. Nothing has been 'published' at this point. `subscriptionData` comes out as:

```
{
  data: {
    branchUpdated: null
  }
}
```

On the server, I can see why. In my `resolverMap`, `Subscription.branchUpdated.resolve` is hit immediately. `payload` is `undefined`, probably, again, because *I haven't published anything yet*. `Subscription.branchUpdated.subscribe` is never executed.

When I *do* publish an update to my "branch", nothing happens. Neither `branchUpdated` nor `subscribe` are invoked, even though I've called `pubSub.publish`. Nothing is returned to the client.

So my questions are:

1. How do I get my subscriptions to *not* fire until I've actually published something
2. More importantly, how do I get them *to* fire when I actually *do* publish something?

Comment: `{subscribe}` is not defined in graphql@0.9.6, need at least 0.10 I believe. That was one of my problems. `SubscriptionServer` won't complain when you pass it `undefined`, and the `import` won't complain either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out. There were a few problems.

1. `graphql@0.9.6` doesn't have `{subscribe}`, you need at least v0.10
2. This was a problem specific to my implementation, but my `withFilter` was wrong. `branch.id` is a buffer -- I needed to use [`.equals`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_equals_otherbuffer) to compare them
3. I updated `componentDidMount`:

   ```
   componentDidMount() {
       this.props.data.subscribeToMore({
           document: SUBSCRIPTION_QUERY,
           variables: {
               id: this.props.match.params.id,
           },
           updateQuery: (prevResult, {subscriptionData}) => {
               log('updateQuery',prevResult,subscriptionData.data.branchUpdated);
               return {branch: subscriptionData.data.branchUpdated};
           }
       });
   }
   ```